# How do I make in-app purchases appear within my apps on all of my devices?

Tags: in-app-purchase

I have purchased an in-app purchase for flightradar24 on my iPhone, and the in-app purchase has not appeared on my other devices.

The app itself has synced to my other devices, however, when I purchased the add-on 'Arrivals & Departure' for £1.99 it only appears on the device I purchased it from, not on my other devices.

How can I get the 'Arrivals & Departure' in-app purchase to appear on my other devices as well?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! If you could add more details to your question, such as what type of in-app-purchase you did, that would help us help you. Thanks!

Comment: I purchased the app called FlightRadar24. The app synced to my devices, however when i purchased the add-on 'Arrivals & Departure' for £1.99 it has only appeared on the device i purchased it from, and not on the rest of my devices.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've used the same Apple ID on all devices you shouldn't have a problem. However, **you will need to restore the in-app purchase** on all devices you didn't originally use to make the purchase.

To do this, you will need to navigate around the app and look for an option labelled something like *restore in-app purchases* (or similar). Many apps will put this option within their own settings page, but I can't advise you exactly where it will be for this app (as I don't personally use it).

If you can't find an option anywhere to restore the in-app purchase, I would go to their dedicated iOS [forum](https://forum.flightradar24.com/threads/3836-Flightradar24-app-on-iOS-(iPhone-iPad-and-iPod)) page and ask for help.